# SharePoint 2013 - Detect when I am in edit mode with CSS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a common id or css file that I can find on a page that SharePoint loads, whenever I enter "edit mode" for a publishing page?  Reason being is because I reeeeallly want to use the following css in my style sheet...

```
#wrapper * {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

But that screws up all the webpart zone areas on the page whenever I enter edit mode for a publishing page.  If there was a class that loaded when I am in editing mode, I could then work something out on disabling or canceling out my wrapper * process.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Why don't you inspect elements that you can only see when the page is in edit mode and take a look at their classes yourself? F12 is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be benefited by using `PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel`, which will add a class to the root element i.e. html tag, when page enters the edit mode.

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" > 
    <script type="text/javascript">
            document.documentElement.className += 'editmode';
    </script> 
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

CSS may look like:

```
<style type="text/css">
        /*
        Only apply the hidden style to elements within the HTML element
        that has the editmode class
        */
        .editmode .description {display:none;}
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer led me directly to a snippet solution for sharepoint 2013 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822364(v=office.15).aspx